# ng-src and onerror : Occasionally hiding a valid image

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter, onerror

In order to show a default image (instead of a broken image) when the image is not physically present, I use this piece of code:

```
<img ng-show="order.img" ng-src="{{order.img | fPath}}" onerror="this.style.display='none';"/>
<img ng-hide="order.img" ng-src="{{'default.png' | imgPath}}" />
```

Here `fPath`,`imgPath` are filters that append a prefix to the image name.

Most of the times it works well (the image gets rendered). However, in some cases the image does not show up. In such cases, the angular snippet gets translated to this html (note the `style="display: none;"` in the first img tag):

```
<img ng-show="order.img" ng-src="http://xx.s3.amazonaws.com/o/img1.jpg" onerror="this.style.display='none'" src="http://xx.s3.amazonaws.com/o/img1.jpg" style="display: none;">
<img ng-hide="order.img" ng-src="http://xx.s3.amazonaws.com/default.png" class="ng-hide" src="http://xx.s3.amazonaws.com/default.png" style="">
```

**Question**: What could be the reason for this? And possible workarounds? Is it that the `onerror` gets triggered sooner than expected?

PS: `http://xx.s3.amazonaws.com/o/img1.jpg` is a valid image path and is available.

**Update**: This is how the app/route/controller is defined

*Route*

```
t_app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
    // ...
    $stateProvider.state('ref', {
        url: '/orders/:ref',
        templateUrl: 'views/order.htm',
        controller: 'orderController'
    });
    // ...
});
```

*Controller*

```
t_app.controller('orderController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', function($scope, $stateParams) {
      // Load the order (this step takes a while)
}]);
```

Comment: How are you declaring your angular app and controller? It could be your page is rendered before the controller is loaded.

Comment: Added some more details. Is your second remark related to `onerror` being triggered sooner than later?

Comment: is the order variable loaded by a remote call? or does it have intermediate values (say, "http://xx.s3.amazonaws.com/" before becoming "http://xx.s3.amazonaws.com/o/img1.jpg")

Comment: `$scope.order` is populated only after a remote call. It is not present until then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what is happening to you is this: http://plnkr.co/edit/8JL0Op?p=preview

```
angular.module('app.helper', [])
.controller('ImgController', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.img = "";
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.img = "9c5595db-db21-4783-902a-8e80b84ae22c/6b89ed2b-878a-4f76-95c4-76ee95f47d9a.jpg";
  }, 1500);
}]);
    filter.$inject = ["$filter"];
    angular.module('app.helper').filter('addPath', filter);

    function filter($filter) {
        function filterFn(input) {
            return "http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/"+input;
        }

        return filterFn;
    }
```

The filter adds the prefix before `order.img` is set, so the img src will be (until order is lodaded) the prefix only, without the image name, resulting in a wrong src.
I think, but i can't be 100% sure, the reason because it happens only sometimes is that sometime `$scope.order` is loaded before (maybe when the results are cached or something) onerror triggers and some times after.
It's hard to determine the execution order when you mix native javascript and angular

You can probably avoid this by adding a check in your filter: if the value passed to the filter is null, undefined or an empty string then return null in that case. Something like this

```
return typeof input === "undefined" || input === null || input === "" ? null : "http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/"+input;
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, your suspicion looks correct. This is what the html looks like: `<img onerror="console.log(this);" ng-src="http://xx.s3.amazonaws.com/o/" src="http://xx.s3.amazonaws.com/o/">`. And yes, I wasn't being defensive in my filter. I think ng-src takes care of the component being rendered after the expression can be evaluated but there are multiple evaluations. Once when the $scope.order is null and then when it gets populated.

Comment: yes, like anything else you use in your view when using angular, it gets evaluated whenever angular does its digest, checking if values are changed in the meantime. Should you change your order.img variable it'll get evaluated again and change the image's src

Comment: other than checking for empty values in your filter (which should be done nonetheless) you can also set a default order.img value pointing to a transparent image or a "Loading" image while waiting for the true image path